# Does this function have a minimum in $\overline \Omega$?

Tags: real-analysis

First I had to prove that for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ there exist one unique $z=z(x,y)$ s.t. $y^3z^3+(x^2+y^2+1)z-2=0$ and that was easy. Then in $\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y>0\}$ see that the function

$f(x,y)= z(x,y)$ if $y>0$ or $2/(x^2+1)$ if $y=0$. I saw that it was $\mathcal C^ \infty$ in $\Omega$ and continous in $\overline \Omega$.

Lastly I'm asked to see that $f(x,y)$ has a maximum   in $\overline \Omega$ and that it is $2.$

But the part I didn't know how to approach was the last one, I'm asked if $f(x,y)$ has a minimum in  in $\overline \Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First scan for critical points in $\Omega$.Taking partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$ yields
\begin{align}
z_x[3z^2y^3 + (x^2+y^2-1)]+2xz&=0 \\
z_y[3z^2y^3 + (x^2+y^2-1)]+3y^2z^3+2yz&=0
\end{align}

In order for $z_x=z_y=0$, we need
\begin{align}
2xz=0 \\
3y^2z^3+2yz=yz(3yz^2+2)=0
\end{align}
Clearly, $z\neq 0$ so $x=0$ from the first equation. In the second, notice that $3yz^2+2=0$ does not have a solution when $y\geq0$. Hence, we must have $y=0$. In other words, a critical point occurs on $\partial \Omega$ at $(0,0)$.

Finally, all this shows that there are no local maximums or minimums on the interior of $\overline{\Omega}$. On the boundary, the maximum of $\frac{2}{x^2+1}$ occurs at $x=0$.

The next question is whether there is a maximum. If not, there are two possibilities. The one is that $z(x,y)$ diverges positively as $x\to \pm \infty$ or $y\to \infty$. The other is that $z(x,y)$ converges in one of these limits to $L>2$. We can rule both scenarios out by the following observation. By letting $y\to\infty$, if $z(x,y)>0$, then we get $\infty=0$, a contradiction.

Similarly, if we let $x\to \pm \infty$, $y>0$ and we assume $z>0$, then we arrive at another contradiction of $\infty=0$. Running the same argument, but assuming $z<0$, we get the contradictions $-\infty=0$. Hence, it must be true that $z\to 0$ as $x\to \pm\infty$ or $y\to\infty$.

Therefore, the absolute maximum occurs at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ where $f(x,y)=2$. There is no absolute minimum, and in fact, $z>0$. This is true since $z>0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $z=0$ can never occur or else the original equation would read $-2=0$, a contradiction.